# C++ template metaprogramming - return a type based on runtime input

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am trying to create a templatized vector, where the template type is determined by runtime parameters.  I am aware that template stuff is completed before runtime, basically I am trying to funnel runtime input into a select few previously selected compile-time types.  Here's a high level example of what I'd like to be able to do.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    std::vector<getRunTimeT(i)> v;

    // Do stuff with v
}
```

So, the vector should be initialized with a type selected by the runtime input.

So far, I've come to the conclusion that specialized template meta-programming is needed, and I have functionality that does what I need with *compile*-time parameters:

```
template<int i>
struct getCompileTimeT
{
    typedef int type; // Base case, not expected to occur.
};

template<>
struct getCompileTimeT<0>
{
    typedef int type;
};

template<>
struct getCompileTimeT<1>
{
    typedef float type;
};
```

So I can do this:

```
std::vector<getCompileTimeT(1)> type; // Creates a vector of floats
```

So, somehow I need to bridge the compile-time aspect with some function that selects the correct type from the predefined template types.  Here is an (**illegal**) example of how I envision this bridging function to work:

```
// Illegal demonstrative desired functionality
_type_ getRunTimeT(int select)
{
    if (select == 0) return getCompileTimeT<0>;
    else if (select == 1) return getCompileTimeT<1>;
}
```

So basically I am looking for something that 'bridges' between the compile-time functionality and the run-time functionality I've spoken of.  Is this possible?

Thanks for any help you can give!

EDIT: Additional info:

Thank you for the solutions thus far; they have been very useful in helping me to understand this more thoroughly.  I would like to provide an API-type function where a user can manipulate or use a type, which is 'dynamic' from their perspective.  For example:

```
UserClass::function()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        // getType() is something that may be a template parameter
        myFunc<getType(i)>();
    }
}

template<class T>
void UserClass::myFunc()
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    // Now the user has a vector to play with in their member function.
}
```

Comment: Do not return a type based on run time input, for that is impossible.  Instead realize there is no spoon, um, I mean run code with a different type (from a list) based off said input.

Comment: C++ doesn't have the reflection to do what you want exactly.  The closest would be if all the possible types shared a base class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
template <class T>
void do_stuff()
{
    std::vector<T> v;
    // Do stuff with v
}

void do_suff_dispatch(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            do_stuff<int>();
            break;
        case 1:
            do_stuff<float>();
            break;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
    do_suff_dispatch(i);
}
```

Comment: Note that in C++11 it is possible to automate the writing of `do_suff_dispatch` with some arcane invocations

Comment: This is a nice solution.  Is there any way for the stuff/do_stuff() functionality to allow the resulting type T to propagate back into the scope of the 'for' loop?  Basically to make it more generalizable.  In my application, I would like to allow users in the scope of the 'for' loop to be able to manipulate the resulting vector (or any other container!) as they wish, and I cannot see how that would be possible (which it might not be).  I will edit my original post with more detailed info.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to a static typed language. One variable can only have one type, it can't change type at runtime. The only workaround I can think of is using `boost::variant` as oakad suggested in his answer.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help!  I'll look into variant a bit more.  One reservation I have with variants is that I'm not sure of the size of the resulting variant - for my application it is very important that the type selected is the proper width.  For example, if I had a float and a long as possibilities for the variant, if float was chosen, would the result be the right length?  My first impression is that variants look similar to unions, which take the width of their longest contained type.  Unfortunately this is not acceptable for my application.

Comment: it will have right size _after_ you get value out of the variant, size of `boost::variant` itself is meaningless

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using boost::variant<> as a type preserving generic value store:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html

The idea goes as following:

```
typedef boost::variant<
    getCompileTimeT<0>,
    getCompileTimeT<1>
> variant_type;

variant_type getRunTimeT(int select)
{
    if (select == 0) return variant_type(getCompileTimeT<0>());
    else if (select == 1) return variant_type(getCompileTimeT<1>());
}
```

At this stage, you can rely on variant's visitor pattern (described in variant's tutorial) to do type safe value dispatch down the line.

Depending on your application and with a bit of template magic (especially on c++11) you can define the original variant type concisely over range of `getCompileTimeT<>` template parameters (so no need to enumerate all explicitly).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I believe that unfortunately I cannot use this method (although it is intriguing) because I don't believe I can get a templatable type from it.  By that, I mean that I can create a vector of `boost::variant` objects, but I believe I cannot use the return type from getRunTimeT to actually create a `vector<float>` or `vector<int>`, for example.  This is required by my application, because one of the things that needs to be done is to pass the resultant vector into a library that needs a vector of one of these native types.